# Specific usage of the word 'but'

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

The [Aesop's Fables translated by George Fyler Townsend](http://www2.hn.psu.edu/faculty/jmanis/aesop/Fables6x9.pdf) book has a line which reads as follows:

> ... If you had but touched me, my friend, you ...

I've seen the word 'but' used this way a couple of times, but I'm not sure I understand the meaning of this phrase correctly. What is the general rule for using 'but' this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the fragment

> ... If you had but touched me, my friend, you ...

*but* functions as an adverb whose **definition**, according to the New Oxford American Dictionary (2nd Edition) is

> no more than; only

Thus, your example could very well read

> - ... If *only* you had touched me, my friend, you ...

Other examples:

> - I am *but* a mere mortal.
> - He is *but* a child.
> - That was *but* a distant memory.

This usage of *but*, though, is largely restricted to formal or literary contexts.

Answer (score 4):

In this case "but" could be replaced with "merely" to give the sense of something small or trivial.

This construction is usually seen when the speaker is reproaching someone for over-reacting when a small action could have prevented a problem. For example,

> If you had but (merely) touched me, I would have awakened showing you I was not dead and you would not have called the police.

Or

> If you had but (merely) asked, I would have agreed. But you didn't and now we are both disappointed.

Answer (score 3):

*But* here means *only*. The phrase then translates to *if you had only touched me* which means that the hypothesis need not be strengthened for the conclusion to be true.

Comment: Where is it applicable to use 'but' this way? Is it an Old-English meaning or not?