# Interpreting the meaning of 'but' as an implication for exclusion/inclusion

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, ambiguity

I often find it difficult to interpret the meaning of *but* in some of the sentences where it is used to imply exclusion/inclusion. For example: *Drink everything you want but alcohol*.

Also, sometimes *but* is used to imply inclusion, however I don't remember any example on top of my mind right now.

Could you explain with examples how to interpret the meaning of *but* in these types of sentences?

Comment: Related: [The construction of “Known but to God”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9235/) ◊ [“All but” idiom has two meanings?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9967/) ◊ [Specific usage of the word 'but'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/) ◊ [“to have all but X”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/) ◊ [“nothing but” vs. “anything but” vs. “everything but”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/).

Comment: "The paths of glory lead but to the grave."

Comment: See also [_Nobbut_-Clefts](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Edited]**

> The Holy Roman Emperor had but a dozen
>   domains left under his direct
>   control.

Here *but* means "only"..

> Drink everything you want but alcohol.

Here it means "except": everything except alcohol. It means "except" when two things are mentioned, both the whole (*everything*) and a part (*alcohol*). In the first example above, no whole was mentioned, so that *but* had to mean "only a dozen domains"—but not so here. You could say *but* without a "whole" is short for *nothing but*, which fits the meaning nicely. Perhaps this is actually how *but* without a whole came to mean *only*, but I haven't researched it.

> She was all but killed by the
>   assassin.

Here it means "except" as well. The "whole" is *all*. Then we get "all except killed"; this means that the assassin came very close to killing her, but he did not actually kill her. She might be badly wounded, or she might have quickly ducked behind the statue when he fired. "Short of" has roughly the same sense.

All senses of *but* probably come from some older sense similar to "only" or "except": if the "except" cases came from "only not" and "not" had been dropped somewhere along the way, it would all be logical; but I'm not sure whether that is how it came to be as it is now.

> She left me behind at the gas station,
>   except she came back later out of
>   guilt.

In informal language you might hear this; you could even use *only* instead.

The funny thing is that you can see a similar development in some other languages. In Dutch, *maar* means both "but" as in "I like you but you stink" and "but" as in "I have but (only) two socks left". But if you wanted to use *maar* with the sense "except", you'd need a negation (which is only logical).

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks.  +1 for your precept: 1. If there's a whole and a part, then **but = only**. This case imports inclusion for **but**. 2. If there's only a whole (I daresay but a whole), then **but = except.** This case connotes exclusion for **but**.

Comment: @LePressentiment: Great! But it seems you've made a typo: you have accidentally switched 1 and 2 around. Number 1 "a whole and part" should be "except", number 2 "only a whole" should be "only" in your comment, right?