# Problem with the usage of "but"

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specific usage of the word 'but'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/specific-usage-of-the-word-but)
>   [Interpreting the meaning of 'but' as an implication for exclusion/inclusion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/interpreting-the-meaning-of-but-as-an-implication-for-exclusion-inclusion)
>   [“nothing but” vs. “anything but” vs. “everything but”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/nothing-but-vs-anything-but-vs-everything-but)

What does this sentence mean:

> For girls who love everything under the sun, but cricket.

I'm a bit confused with the "but" usage here.

Answer (score 4):

In this sentence, *but* it is a **preposition** meaning ***“except”, “apart from”, “other than”***.

Comment: +1 : A short but complete answer.