# Difference between "but" and "nothing but"

Tags: differences

Every now and then I stumble about a construction like this:

> It was but something....

and I understand it to be

> It was nothing but....

or

> It was only...

depending on the context.

I do know what this "but" means and I do know what else "but" can mean. My question is this?

Is the a difference between "but" and "nothing but" in this context, be it ever so small and hidden in tone or emphasis? Is there such a difference between "but" and "only"? And finally is "but" in this context something you can say or does that make you sound way out there? Thanks a lot

Comment: Related and possible dupe: [Specific usage of the word 'but'](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8892/), [Interpreting the meaning of 'but' as an implication for exclusion/inclusion](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14078/), [The construction of “Known but to God”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9235/), [“All but” idiom has two meanings?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9967/), [“to have all but X”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9323/), [“nothing but” vs. “anything but” vs. “everything but”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8061/), and a dozen more.

Comment: sorry I did search before I posted and stackexchange did not show one of these... I'll read and possible delete the question

Comment: ok I read them... I do know what it means... I want to know whether there is a small difference in tone or meaning or emphasis so I stand by my question :)

Comment: You don't just "stand by". Please edit the question accordingly. Responders will see the Q., not these comments.

Comment: true... I did. I hope it is clear enough know what I am going for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They all mean the same thing, as you note. However:

1. *Nothing but* implies that the subject (*it) was more overblown than with the lone *but*, hence the *nothing*.
2. There is no great difference in meaning between *but* and *only*. The NOAD defines *but* (adv.) as "no more than; only," while defining *only* (adv.) as "and no one or nothing more besides; solely or exclusively."
3. *But* is older and/or more poetic; you might get funny stares if you use it in normal speech. For this reason you would normally use *only*.