# What does "it is but X" mean?

Tags: phrases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specific usage of the word ‘but’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/specific-usage-of-the-word-but)

What does “It is but X” mean?

For example, as in “Yes; however, they are but thoughts.”

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question it was closed as a dupe of. Voting to reopen.

Comment: But it ***is*** a dup of [the one I linked to!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/specific-usage-of-the-word-but) It just so happens that the *first* dup closevote incorrectly cited a different question. And because that used used up my vote, I can't closevote again!

Answer (score 9):

*But* in your sentence means *only*.

Comment: To add to that, it means *only* in the sense of not very important or significant.

Comment: That's because it mimics the idiom _only thoughts_; i.e, that's the usual interpretation of _only_ in this construction, so _but_ gets it too, if it means 'only'.

Comment: Well illustrated in Jane Austen’s ‘Sense and Sensibility’: "It is **but** a cottage," she continued, "but I hope to see many of my friends in it."

Comment: A less ambiguous synonym is "merely".

Comment: You could think of an omitted "nothing" before the "but", as in `they are nothing but thoughts`.