# What does "be it" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "be it" mean in this sentence?

> Be it stated, in course of hearing we have found that a series of interlocutory applications seeking similar reliefs have been filed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "be it" mean in this passage?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214687/what-does-be-it-mean-in-this-passage)

Comment: @choster.  Disagree.  The other has the sense of "whether" and this one has the sense of the imperative "let."

Comment: @cobaltduck Fair enough, although traditionally both would have been called different examples of the subjunctive.

Comment: Interesting.  Imperative and subjunctive at the same time.  You've got to love legalese.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What does your own research show about the usage and meaning of the phrase? Questions without any research are considered off-topic. You can take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good questions.

Comment: Where did you get this from?  It is not English because "in course of hearing" cannot occur.

Answer (score 1):

"Be it stated" can be uses as a sort of passive version of "Let it be stated".  It's a formal/archaic construction, but reasonably idiomatic.  In the above quotation it's basically saying "let it be noted for the record".

It can also be used in other contexts, though, so some interpretation is needed.

Comment: *It's a formal/archaic construction,* It is from the case "STATE OF UTTAR PRADESH AND OTHERS V. SHIV KUMAR PATHAK AND OTHERS (2017)5 SCC 247"
Order dated 24-8-2016 (Before Dipak Misra and Chockalingam Nagappan, JJ.) *4. Be it stated, in course of hearing we have found that a series of interlocutory applications seeking similar reliefs have been filed. Some of the learned counsel appearing for the parties submitted that regard being had to the earlier orders, especially order dated 24-2-2016, the matter shall be heard on merits.* https://www.casemine.com/judgement/in/5a65cbab4a932633207776e3